# Why are the text editor options not available in mobile view?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web

While traveling, I just opened the site in my mobile, and I wanted to make some updates on my post based on the comments of the OP, but the content editor tools (I inspect them in the browser, `wmd-button-bar`; their style property `display` is set to `none` for responsive view) are not available in mobile view.

Here I request you to enable them in responsive view too, or let me ask why it is not available in the mobiles.

[image: Screen shot for reference]

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the "why", but if you want markdown toolbar when writing a question/answer, consider using Stack Exchange official app ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8), I hope you're not using Windows Phone...).

[image: markdown toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is not enough space for them. Once you get used to [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), you'll find it even easier and faster to type them by yourself.

If you still insist to have them, you can tick the "Request desktop site" which will open the full site.